# Destination Host Unreachable between linux boxes

Tags: networking, ubuntu, tcp

I have a home wifi network with 2 linux and 1 mac system. I can reach each linux from mac and other way round, but an attempt to ping a linux from another linux results with "Destination Host Unreachable" error on both systems.

What may cause it, and how to fix it? I disabled all firewalls on both linux systems:

```
iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

yet it didn't help much.

Details:

pc (ubuntu 16.04):

```
ifconfig:
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:0e
          inet addr:192.168.1.83  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

route:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0

arp:
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.254            ether   58:90:43:49:eb:6b   C                     wlp2s0
192.168.1.77             ether   34:02:86:aa:89:85   C                     wlp2s0
192.168.1.69             ether   18:65:90:dc:04:55   C                     wlp2s0
```

laptop (ubuntu 16.04):

```
ifconfig: 
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:02:86:aa:89:85
          inet addr:192.168.1.77  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

route:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0

arp:
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.83             ether   ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:0e   C                     wlan0
192.168.1.69             ether   18:65:90:dc:04:55   C                     wlan0
192.168.1.254            ether   58:90:43:49:eb:6b   C                     wlan0
```

mac (10.13.3):

```
ifconfig:
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 18:65:90:dc:04:55
    inet6 fe80::80f:e846:2fe6:90c5%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5
    inet 192.168.1.69 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255

route:    
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.254      UGSc          105        0     en0
192.168.1          link#5             UCS             4        0     en0
192.168.1.69/32    link#5             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.1.77       34:2:86:aa:89:85   UHLWI           0      510     en0   1154
192.168.1.83       ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:e   UHLWIi          2       55     en0    915
192.168.1.254/32   link#5             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.1.254      58:90:43:49:eb:6b  UHLWIir        39    14075     en0   1169
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCS             0        0     en0
```

Ping from pc to mac works:

```
ping 192.168.1.69
PING 192.168.1.69 (192.168.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=6.15 ms
```

Ping from pc to laptop does not:

```
ping 192.168.1.77
PING 192.168.1.77 (192.168.1.77) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.83 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Ping from laptop to mac works:

```
ping 192.168.1.69
PING 192.168.1.69 (192.168.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.89 ms
```

Ping from laptop to pc does not:

```
ping 192.168.1.83
PING 192.168.1.83 (192.168.1.83) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Ping from mac to pc works:

```
ping 192.168.1.83
PING 192.168.1.83 (192.168.1.83): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.83: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=101.836 ms
```

Ping from mac to laptop works as well:

```
ping 192.168.1.77
PING 192.168.1.77 (192.168.1.77): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.77: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=16.749 ms
```

Tcpdump from 192.168.1.77 during `telnet 192.168.83 22`:

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 65535 -n host 192.168.1.83
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:38:53.194490 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
18:38:53.410085 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.83 is-at ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:0e, length 46
18:38:53.410100 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7583261 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:38:54.193729 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7583511 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:38:56.197662 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7584012 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:39:00.205734 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7585014 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:39:08.213738 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7587016 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:39:24.245736 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7591024 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:39:29.253720 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
18:39:30.253717 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
18:39:31.253715 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
18:39:56.309737 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 28
18:39:56.321748 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.83 is-at ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:0e, length 46
18:39:56.321762 IP 192.168.1.77.38208 > 192.168.1.83.22: Flags [S], seq 3257644438, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7599040 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Tcpdump from 192.168.1.83 at the same time:

```
tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -s 65535 -n host 192.168.1.77
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:38:53.341294 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 46
18:38:53.341312 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.83 is-at ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:0e, length 28
18:39:56.316562 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.83 tell 192.168.1.77, length 46
18:39:56.316597 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.83 is-at ac:7b:a1:c5:ea:0e, length 28
```

---

**UPDATE**

Apparently I am missing some smart settings in [BT Smart Hub](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/57427/~/learn-about-the-bt-hub-manager). Everything works with less sophisticated router.

Comment: please check and share 'iptables -nL' from both Linux boxes

Comment: @MTG, flushing iptables was the first thing I did. I updated the question with formal output of iptables.

Comment: You can see outgoing packets on .77, but no incoming packets on .83, so the first guess would be that the router is blocking them. Some routers need to be configured to allow WLAN clients to talk to each other, possibly for all involved clients. So the next step is to look into the webinterface of your router (enable all "advanced options") etc.

Comment: @dirkt, Thanks for the hint. Do you know what exactly I need to enable on the router? It is [BT Smart Hub](https://www.productsandservices.bt.com/broadband/smart-hub). Somehow it let macbook to talk to both linux systems and I can reach macbook from linuxes as well, so I assume the router allows WLAN clients to talk to each other in general, but drops packets between .77 and .83. I will get another router to try it on the weekend.

Comment: No idea about the BT Smart Hub. Most routers display a web page when you enter the address in a browser, so try `http://192.168.1.254`. It's possible (though this is a wild guess) that the Mac uses Bonjour to make some adjustments to what it is allowed to do; Linux boxes don't do this by default. But one would have to sniff the Mac WLAN traffic when it connects to find out if this is the case.

Comment: @dirkt, I can access the router web UI. It's just that it has a lot of things there with no real documentation, so I am a bit lost what I need to change there. Thanks for the idea about Bonjour tho. It's worth checking.

Comment: Without actually seeing the router web UI, I can't guide you, sorry. In general, every router UI will have its own way of presenting these features. You are looking for something like "client isolation", or general filter rules.